# How to use ControlClick without controlid?

Tags: qt, automation, autoit

I want to use AutoIt for automation tests of my project developed in Qt Creator, but the finder tool in AutoIt Window Information Tool cannot access the GUI. So I used UIAspy. According to the tutorial in AutoIt you can click somewhere with `ControlClick("title", "text", controlid)`, but there is no controlid in UIAspy.

Comment: ControlID is optional. Give it a try without a value.